# How to give negative feedback to unprofessional company?

Tags: internship, feedback, unprofessional-behavior, complaint

I'm a student, just ended my 3 months attachment programme that provide by my school. I have been assign to one of the IT Company that are not professional. I have done well, perform good attitude and hardworking throughout my attachment. But then I was so disappointed when I have received my logbook for my grade by the company. I does not expect that they graded me low.

Furthermore my Team Leader do not show good attitude manner and used vulgarities words when carry out work and instruction by him. My daily plan work schedule was not given in advance during my 3 months of attachment. There's a lot of difficulties face in this job, also they did not show a high standard of schedule planned. My supervisor in-charge did not email us schedule earlier, perhaps he email the schedule and location at every day late night for the deployment. I’m a lady was assigned to carry heavy equipment and boxes from up to level 4 by staircase till I have a backache, scratches, wound around my hand and finger.

Hope you guys can help or give me a proper sample negative feedback or complaint to that company.

Comment: Most of what you describe sounds like the vast majority of companies I've worked with!

Comment: The comment you made that you should have been exempted from carrying equipment because of your gender indicates that the problem is not entirely on the company's side.

Comment: I would not be happy with a woman who worked for me that didn't want to move equipement if it needed to be moved. And I am a woman and I have moved my fair share of equipment.  Those kinds of tasks are necessary and needed no matter what your job classification and they tend to fall on the younger people.

Answer (score 3):

First, ask yourself which is more important to you:

- letting your academic institution know that this is an unprofessional company (or department) and they shouldn't send other students there in future?
- letting your academic institution know that you disagree with the poor rating you've been assigned?
- letting the company or department know they have areas in which they should improve?

Your title suggests it's #3, but I would recommend that you not try to let the company know your assessment of them. Many teams, companies, and people who are not good at their jobs reject criticism from others, especially from inexperienced others. They are likely to reply "that's just an angry and bitter response from someone who didn't do well here."

If you then turn your attention to #1 and #2, instead of complaining to the company, you can complain to your academic institution. There is probably some sort of co-ordinator or liaison officer you can talk to about this. If you start mostly by talking about #1, and wanting to spare other students the chaos, disorganization, and physical difficulties you experienced, you may find that #2 is taken care of along the way. Or, you may find that your expectations of what a job should be like in your industry were wrong, and your advisor can help you to understand which of your problems were due to flaws in the company, and which were due to skills you still need to develop. This is one of the goals of these "work while learning" programs - that you will learn to navigate the workplace. That includes dealing with disorganized or rude coworkers.

I don't know what level of scheduling and planning is normal in your industry or whether your expectations are right or wrong. But I expect that the person assigned to help students with their work placements does know. This person can advise you or can advise the company to change their ways. This person may even stop sending students to the company in future. Start with this person and don't correspond directly with the company about their behaviour.